# How to use office js api to open a new appointment window with prepopulated fields

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have a web application(html/js) and would like to open this window (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yZwD.png) upon a click of a button. I am currently trying to execute this code taken from this [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-mailbox-displaynewappointmentformasync-member(2)) for outlook javascript api. However I am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'displayNewAppointmentFormAsync'). Thanks in advance

```
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();
end.setHours(start.getHours() + 1);

// The async version is only available starting with requirement set 1.9,
// and provides a callback when the new appointment form has been created.
Office.context.mailbox.displayNewAppointmentFormAsync(
  {
    requiredAttendees: ["bob@contoso.com"],
    optionalAttendees: ["sam@contoso.com"],
    start: start,
    end: end,
    location: "Home",
    subject: "meeting",
    resources: ["projector@contoso.com"],
    body: "Hello World!"
  },
  function(asyncResult) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(asyncResult));
  }
);
```

Comment: When and where do you call this method?

Comment: According to the documentation, this API is only supported when you are on a ReadItem. Are you trying to run this API while composing an email, or while you are reading a received email? Here's the link with more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-preview#outlook-office-mailbox-displaynewappointmentformasync-member(1)